# VS 2010 SQL Server Compact adding Now in DB table edit view

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I am using the Entity Framework and SQL Server Compact Edition through the code first methodology. This is my first project using these techniques, and I'm working from Scott Guthrie's [excellent introduction](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx) to it.

I am currently populating my database using the `Show Table Data` option from within VS2010's Server Explorer. Here's where I am right now:

[image: Imgur]

Created is a `DateTime` column, and I want to say I'm creating it now. Is there a way to put that, instead of having to write out a date and time?

EDIT: I'm specifically looking for something like C#'s `DateTime.Now()` method.

Comment: set allow null = true for that field on the table design. If you want to hard-code it , it will be in the format like : 2012-01-07 02:10:12.307

Comment: oh, so allow it to be null, and have it default in the DB to `Now`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesse , add this to the default value or binding area

[image]

SQL Server 2008 R2    `{ fn NOW() }`

Earlier Version `(getdate())`

Comment: It failed with an error: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number =1, Token line offset = 73, Token in error = NOW ]

Comment: What version of SQL Server you are working with ? That works for me on SQL Server 2008. Ok could you try this ? See my edited answer.

Comment: Apparently, when using Visual Studio 2010, `(getdate())` should be used. Thank you!